# Rotating strings in Java

Tags: java, strings

I have this Java class for producing rotations of an input string:

**StringRotator.java**

```
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * This class implements a data type for rotating strings.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Mar 24, 2016)
 */
public class StringRotator {

    /**
     * The source string. All rotations will be produced from this string.
     */
    private final String string;

    /**
     * Caches the length of the source string in order to by a little of 
     * efficiency.
     */
    private final int length;

    /**
     * Caches the current rotation. This field is set to {@code null} after 
     * every effective rotation. Whenever the user requests the rotated string,
     * if this field is not {@code null}, the cached string is returned. 
     * Otherwise, a rotated string is built and set to this field, and finally
     * returned.
     */
    private String cachedString;

    /**
     * Index of the first logical character component in the source string.
     */
    private int finger;

    public StringRotator(String string) {
        this.string = Objects.requireNonNull(string, 
                                             "The input string is null.");
        this.length = string.length();
    }

    public void rotate(int offset) {
        int oldFinger = finger;
        finger += offset;
        finger %= string.length();

        if (finger != oldFinger) {
            cachedString = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (cachedString != null) {
            return cachedString;
        }

        return cachedString = buildString();
    }

    private String buildString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);

        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            sb.append(string.charAt((finger + i) % length));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; ++c) {
            sb.append(c);
        }

        String input = sb.toString();

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i) {
            StringRotator string = new StringRotator(input);
            string.rotate(i);
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
}
```

Please, tell me anything that comes to mind.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Simplicity

To rotate a string, only the string itself and the offset of rotation are needed.

A class is a way to store data in an orderly manner, but for the task of rotating a string, you do not need such storage.

In Java not needing a class is signalled by the use of static methods.

Also, using  [`String.substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) you can avoid the manual looping. In short all your program can be reduced to:

```
public static String rotate(String s, int offset) {
  int i = offset % s.length();
  return s.substring(i) + s.substring(0, i);
}
```

The example usage is also simplified, as you do not need to build a new class:

```
public static void main(final String... args) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    System.out.println(rotate("abcdefg", i));
  }
}
```

The drawback of this approach is that it *may* be slower and/or use more memory, but unless you want to rotate a string tens of millions of times per second it should not matter.

Comment: You should apply modulus to the offset to maintain functionality

Comment: @Pimgd amended the code.

Answer (score 3):

I personally don't like classes which encapsulate internally only algorithms but not really needed data (the sign of such classes are `-or` or `-er` suffixes). It's actually, sign of procedural programming but not OOP.

So,

1. I would create class with name `RotableString` and implement for it interface `java.lang.CharSequence`
2. make the class immutable and don't use any internal cached strings. Only link to the source string and offset as the constructor parameters `RotableString(CharSequence source, int offset)`
3. if you need to do new rotation from some `CharSequence` implementation (`java.lang.String`, your `RotableString`, `java.lang.StringBuilder` etc.) just create a new `RotableString` instance as a [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) with appropriate source and new offset.
4. remove static `main` method from the class body and add some unit tests instead in a separate file.
5. as a bonus have thread-safety implementation as your class is immutable :)

**UPDATE** I also suggest not to do any *premature optimization* till it'll be a real problem and you can *confirm it* with a profile. See [When to optimize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize) paragraph.

Comment: Why would you say that keeping track of what the current rotation is isn't part of storing data?

Answer (score 3):

A couple things:

Your `toString` seemed backwards to me... and the `return a = b();` format struck me as a poor choice. I like the following much better:

```
public String toString() {
    if (cachedString == null) {
        cachedString = buildString();
    }
    return cachedString;
}
```

Also, your `buildString` might be slightly more efficient than mine, but I think mine is a lot more elegant and not significantly slower.

```
private String buildString() {
    return string.substring(finger) + string.substring(0,finger);
}
```

I did consider getting rid of `buildString` altogether, putting that logic in the rotate method and then having `toString` always return the cache. Up to you.

You optimize by storing `final int length` but honestly, that's unnecessary. It's already final by being a property of the String (which indeed you use in your rotate method instead of the cached length...) and you can expect it to get JIT'd 110% of the time.

One final note is that your test does the exact same test 26 times. As moderator of [Software Quality Assurance Stack Exchange](http://sqa.stackexchange.com), I hereby give your test driver a D+. (It would have been a D- but seeing the rotated alphabet in my command prompt was oddly satisfying... :-)

Try some other funky tests:

```
string.rotate(-1);
string.rotate(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
string.rotate(0);
string.rotate(input.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rotating a string as an operation involves appending a substring from the begining of the string to a substring from the start of the string.

This can be stated as taking a substring of the string appended to itself, a fact that one would use if you write a function to determine if a string is a rotation of some other string.

So rather than store the input string you want to store the input string appended to itself.

```
public StringRotator(String string) {
    this.string = Objects.requireNonNull(string, 
                                         "The input string is null.");
    this.string = this.string.append(string);
    this.length = string.length();
}
```

You can then write your buildString as

```
private String buildString() 
{
    return string.substring(finger,length);
}
```